# Automatic DVD to .iso copy after disc insert with two drives

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, optical-drive, dvd

I have a lot of DVDs (Movies) that I want to save as an .iso preferably using `dd`. To speed up the process I have two drives.

I'd like to set up a script (pure bash or bash + AppleScript combination) that runs on insert. macOS allows to configure a script in *Settings › CDs & DVDs › On insert…*

The process should look like this:

1. Insert DVD in one of the two drives
2. Script starts and checks which drive triggered the command (hardest part for me)
3. Opens a Terminal window and runs the actual script

A rough draft of what my idea is:

```
#!/bin/bash
diskutil umountDisk /dev/THEDRIVE
echo -n `date "+%Y-%m-%d - %H:%M:%S -> Starting with DISCTITLE"` >> iso.log
dd if=/dev/THEDRIVE | pv -s DRIVESIZE | dd of=/myfolder/DISCTITLE.iso
echo -n `Finished DISCTITLE, took TIME. Ejecting.`
drutil tray eject -drive DRIVENUMBER
```

4. Close the Terminal window after ejecting

UnmountDisk for `dd`, write to log, copy with status using `pv`, write to log again and eject the disc after finishing.

What I don't know is how I get the part with the two drives right. And set up the script so that it handles it right.

`drutil status` tells size and device. `mount` tells the name. But I have, of course, always both drives present.

**How could I use e.g. `awk` or `sed` to get device/mountpoint, disc title, size and drivenumber (to eject the right one) of the current disc?**

Comment: Are these commercial DVD's and if yes how do you plan to get past the copy protection?

Comment: @user3439894 yes, private backup copies for mostly movies, series, no games or data. Want to get rid of the physical copies. I've tried by hand with one and had no problem opening the .iso created with `dd` with VLC. I thought about the copy protection too, but my first attempt did just work.

Comment: @user3439894 I thought about using Burn.app or similar. But Burn crashes and is discontinued (looks like most DVD related tools for macOS are).

Comment: @user3439894 looks like the DVD even has a copy protection. I've just tried opening it with Handbrake (didn't know how to find out) and it showed the notice "copy protected sources not supported…". Is it possible that `dd` bypasses the problem by nature?

Comment: HandBrake requires libdvdcss to read copy CSS protected discs. But there are many other kinds of DVD copy protections besides CSS, such as Sony ArccOS, UOPs, and Disney X-project DRM that libdvdcss won't work with.

Comment: @user3439894 you were right. Tried some samples and got a `Permission denied` for one of the newer discs. Problem with most GUI tools I've tried is: You can run only one instance of the tool at a time, so I can't utilize two drives. You aren't aware of an alternative to dd on the command line that can bypass the most common copy protections? Or a GUI tool that allows multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it very easily.

After comparing Mac DVD Ripper Pro, MacX DVD Ripper Pro (don't confuse the two), RipIt and AnyDVD for Windows. I decided to use [Mac DVD Ripper Pro](http://www.macdvdripperpro.com/).

It has a setting to start automatically after inserting a DVD and ejecting it after being finished.

I run two instances of the app using `open -n /Applications/MDRP.app`. Since MDRP picks up the first DVD it finds, and the first one won't be available, the second instance will pick up the second DVD drive and vice versa.

Output .iso is not a bitwise copy, since MDRP takes care of the copy protection (at least CSS was no problem) but played well in my tests with VLC and Kodi (on my Media Server).

Only thing I didn't find were log files, but everything else I've been looking for is solved this way.

If you prefer video_ts output over .iso you can do the same thing using RipIt, RipIt also in-officially supports ripping from two drives at the same time.

Note: I haven't yet tried ripping DVDs protected with Sony ArccOS, UOPs, and Disney X-project as mentioned in the comments. CSS protection worked.